# How to go forward/back in Deezer app?

Tags: music-player

In the Deezer Android app, when I play any music, it displays a button "play in shuffle mode". When I click, the track starts playing, but in the track window:

[image]

I can't go to a specific position in the song, the progress bar is thinnest and even when I click,the track window just minimizes.
Isn't there a progress bar where I can go to any position?